# How to control mildew/mold growing on soil-less growing medium for (aloe) seed germination?

Tags: seeds, germination, seedlings, aloe

Help, I wanted to check in on the aloes I planted earlier this week.  Making sure there are no problem.  What I find is mildew has started to grow in this new moist environment.  my instinct is to spray with a low dose of Hydrogen Peroxide.  Should I be keeping the top off?  The seeds are covered by this layer, so they should not have any mildew growing on them.  The medium is a blend of 1/2 diatomite and 1/2 turface.

What do I do?

I have had this same problem, every time I have tried the baggy method.

[image: close-up of mildew starting]

[image: lid off]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Took the lid off for the day, long enough for the top of the planting medium to dry.  Then I put the lid back on.  There was enough water in the medium to bring moisture up to the surface.   Starting today, The lid remains propped open during the daytime.  I will also make sure the fan is always running to keep air circulation during the day.  I did today have to mist the top once.
On a wonderful side note.   I have TWO BABIES, possibly three in less than one week!!!

[image: First Born]

[image: Second and Possibly Third]

Comment: Did you sterilize your medium before you started? It's easy to do in a conventional oven and keeps the uninvited guests down to a minimum.

Comment: Tim, I wanted to know how to fix the problem.  Not what I may or may not have done wrong.   That does me no good at this stage in the game.